# CRM 2011 Linking a task to multiple users

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to be able to link an activity (task) to multiple users in CRM 2011.
I thought I would be able to do this by creating a relationship between Task and User and then add users to the task via a sub-grid within the task form.

I thought I had cracked it but then when I log in as a user that I have added a task to I cannot see the task under Activities.

What am I missing? Does this sound like something that is possible?

Comment: Have you considered assigning the task to a team of users instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this if you create Teams to assign the Tasks to.

Remember to put the users inside the teams *and* triple-check the Teams' Security Roles.

Answer (score 0):

> The best way to do this is to create a Team and add the users into
>   that team. At the time when you create task, set your team in
>   regarding of the task.
>
> The other way is to create a custom entity in which you will keep the
>   lookups of user entity in Task, and create a record in this new custom
>   entity with the user and task guid, so that you can have multiple
>   users for one task, which you will be able to show on subgrid by
>   creating your own view.